# socket.io GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LV9VGzC" Error (404): "Not found"

Tags: angularjs, node.js, socket.io

```
//backend code
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var http = require('http');

var startServer=http.createServer(app);
var socketIO = require('socket.io').listen(startServer);
startServer.listen(8080, function () {
    console.log('server running on',8080)
});

socketIO.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>connected')
    var userSocketObject = {};
    userSocketObject.socket_id = socket.id;
    socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
        socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});

//index.html code angularjs
var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8080');
socket.on('news', function(data){
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', {my: 'data'});
});
```

I'm trying to connect but I'm getting an error in the browser:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LV9VGzC" Error (404): "Not found"
```

Comment: Did you include the socket.io js in index.html? Try adding <script src=/socket.io/socket.io.js>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have resolved the problem , the problem was in directory path app.use(express.static(path.join('public')))

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your backend code into

```
var socketio = require('socket.io')(startServer, {
  path: '/socket.io-client'
});

socketio.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

And on the clientside, the easiest way is to follow the instructions given in this repo: https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io

Comment: i tried but still not working, just want to mention the versions i am using are

Comment: socket.io-1.4.5, node v6.0.0

Comment: socket.io-1.4.5, node v6.0.0

Comment: Your versions seems to be fine. Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24172909/socket-io-connection-reverts-to-polling-never-fires-the-connection-handler