# GET http://MY_DOMAIN.com/socket.io?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1449205340962-2 404 (Not found)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I have deployed my code but am unable to get socket.io working in production.

I have installed the socket.io node module with the command `npm install --save socket.io`

Here's the relevant code in my `app.js`:

```
var debug = require('debug')('chat');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), 'APP_PRIVATE_IP_ADDRESS', function() {
  debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});

var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

I am using the browser client
`<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.7.js"></script>`

Also, the following client code does not print connect:

```
var socket = io();
socket.on('connect', function(){
    console.log('connect');
});
```

I appreciate any help!

[Here is my site where I've deployed this code](http://briandaneshgar.com/chat).

Comment: I think what is happening is that you are calling `app.listen` before `require('socket.io')`. Take a look at the Socket.io [docs](http://socket.io/docs/#using-with-express-3/4).

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `express` that way. You should use `http` package to create a server and attach `express` to it by:

```
var httpServer;
var http           = require( "http" );
var express        = require( "express" );
var app            = express();
var io             = require( 'socket.io' )( httpServer ); 

httpServer = http.createServer( app ).listen( process.env.PORT, process.env.IP || "0.0.0.0", function() {  
    // server code here
});
```

Comment: It seems this is not necessary from the [accepted answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17697134/4975582)