# Difference between a server with http.createServer and a server using express in node js

Tags: node.js, express, npm, server

What's the difference between creating a server using http module and creating a server using express framework in node js?
Thanks.

Comment: Really what you're asking is why would one use the Express framework instead of just using the http module.  Basically, you can read about the features of the Express framework and decide if any of those are useful to you.  It's a superset of the http module.

Comment: I am actually novice into node.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Express.js - app.listen vs server.listen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17696801/express-js-app-listen-vs-server-listen)

Comment: Very rude answers conssidering the public interest of the question

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Ultimately, [express](http://expressjs.com/) uses node's [http api](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) behind the scenes.

#### express framework

The express framework provides an abstraction layer above the vanilla http module to make handling web traffic and APIs a little easier. There's also tons of middleware available for express (and express-like) frameworks to complete common tasks such as: CORS, XSRF, POST parsing, cookies etc.

#### http api

The http api is very simple and is used to to setup and manage incoming/outgoing ,HTTP connections. Node does most of the heavy lifting here but it does provide things you'll commonly see throughout most node web framework such as: [`request`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest)/[`response`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse) objects etc.

Answer (score 36):

Express uses the http module under the hood, `app.listen()` returns an instance of http. You would use `https.createServer` if you needed to serve your app using HTTPS, as `app.listen` only uses the http module.

Here's the [source](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/3e4158bcbda7017dbe7226fb76d974bd95c29ce9/lib/application.js#L540) for `app.listen` so you can see the similarities.:

```
app.listen = function(){
  var server = http.createServer(this);
  return server.listen.apply(server, arguments);
};
```