# express and http server usage togather

Tags: node.js, http, express, socket.io

**Gone through code as below couldnt understand the working of code 1...what is the difference between the two codes below**

**

> What is the point of using http and express togather in code 1?

***Code1***

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);

app.get('/', function(req, res)
{
   res.sendFile(__dirname+'/index.html');
});

http.listen(3000, function()
{
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

**The same thing can be done as**

**Code2**

```
var express=require('express');

var app=express();

var socket=require('socket.io');

app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/index.html');

}).listen(8080);
console.log("Listening to port 8080");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking about the difference of expressjs own server and http server. They are different in many ways.

[Solved here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35167824/difference-between-a-server-with-http-createserver-and-a-server-using-express-in)

Answer (score 0):

The app object conventionally denotes the Express application which is created by top level express() function exported by the Express module.

`http.listen()`: Starts the HTTP server listening for connection

In the second case it works `app.listen()` which binds and listens for connection on the specified port and it identical to `http.listen()`