# Listen is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this code and it say this error

> TypeError: app.listen is not a function
>
> ```
>  at mongoose.connect (C:\wamp\www\curso-mean2\index.js:14:7)
>  at C:\wamp\www\curso-mean2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:292:19
>  at open (C:\wamp\www\curso-mean2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:576:17)
> ```
>
> [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Contents of **app.js**:

```
'use strict'

var express = require('express'); // objeto express dentro de variable app
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

// cargar rutas
//configurar body parser
//es necesario para body parse y convierte a objetos Json los datos que llegan por http:
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//configurar cabeceras http

//rutas base

//exportamos el modulo , podemos utilizar express dentro de ficheros que incluyan app
module.exports = app;
```

Contents of **index.js**:

```
'use strict'

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var app = require('./app');
//configurar puerto por defecto
var port = process.env.PORT || 3977;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/curso_mean2', (err,res) => {
    if (err){
        throw err;
    }else{
        console.log("La base de datos esta funcionando muy bien...");
        //a escuchar
        app.listen(port, function () {
            console.log("Servidor del api rest de musica escuchando en http://localhost");
        });
    } //else
});
```

Can you help me, please? I'm a beginner, and I don't know what is happening

Comment: please take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17696801/express-js-app-listen-vs-server-listen

Comment: What if you `console.log(app)` ? @Paolo this doesn't explain why his app.listen doesn't work

Comment: All is fine for me when I execute this pieces of code. Did you have post all your code ? Did you install all your npm module ?

Comment: Try adding the `js` extension. `var app = require('./app.js');`

Comment: I put all the code, in this question. For this is strange. I have tried put app.js, and nothing change.

Answer (score 2):

the underlying MongoDB driver **has deprecated their current connection string parser**. Because this is a major change, they added the **useNewUrlParser** flag to allow users to fall back to the old parser, so you should use something similar like this:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/curso_mean2', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
```

If you wanna catch errors, I suggest you use promises and catch method:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/curso_mean2', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
 .then(()=>{
       console.log("La base de datos esta funcionando muy bien...");

       app.listen(port,function () {
           console.log("Servidor del api rest de musica escuchando en http://localhost");
       });

 })
 .catch( err => console.log(err) );
```

[Here you can found references from connection to MongoDB](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html)