# HTTP connection gets prematurely terminated in nodejs app hosted on Amazon EC2

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, amazon-ec2

I have a REST api hosted on Amazon EC2, which is written with Nodejs (Express).

In a particular REST call, a reply of about 5MB is sent to the client. Before the client completely receives the reply, client prints following error message.

```
Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body
```

I added a connection listener in nodejs server like below to check what is going on the server.

```
var app = express();

var server = http.createServer(app);
var port = app.get('port');
server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);
server.on('connection', function (socket) {
    log.debug('SOCKET OPENED' + JSON.stringify(socket.address()));
    socket.setTimeout(300000);   //5 minute timeout
    socket.on('end', function () {
        log.debug('SOCKET END: other end of the socket sends a FIN packet');
    });

    socket.on('timeout', function () {
        log.warn('SOCKET TIMEOUT');
    });

    socket.on('error', function (error) {
        log.warn('SOCKET ERROR: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
    });

    socket.on('close', function (had_error) {
        log.debug('SOCKET CLOSED. IT WAS ERROR: ' + had_error);
    });
});
```

I observed that `SOCKET TIMEOUT` gets logged in backend. In above code, I have increased the socket timeout to 5 minutes, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Earlier I had the REST API hosted in Google compute engine, and I didn't have this problem back then.

What could be the problem here?

Edit: Here is the code of REST API call.

I have following code in my `app.js`

```
require('./routes/index')(app);
```

Following is the index.js of `routes` directory.

```
var changeCase = require('change-case');
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('require-dir')();

module.exports = function (app) {
    Object.keys(routes).forEach(function (routeName) {
        var router = express.Router();
        require('./' + routeName)(router);
        app.use('/api/' + changeCase.paramCase(routeName), router);
    });
};
```

As it can be seen, it loops through all the js files in the `routes` directory and registers the file name as the URL path in `app`.

Here is the code of this particular route for which I face this problem.

```
   module.exports = function (router) {   
       router.get("/fetch", function (req, res, next) {
            itemModel.fetch(req.user.clientId, function (error, items) {
                if (error) {
                    res.status(500).json({error: error});
                } else {
                    res.json(items);    //items is a JSON array
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: So: where is the REST API? I can only see some WebSocket code ;) Also: how do you send/receive the data? Also: which WebSocket implementation are you using?

Comment: @jsalonen, Added REST API call implementation to the question

Comment: I still don't get it. How is this `GET /fetch` related to WebSocket stuff? What kind of calls you make from your client?

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. My assumption about WebSocket was invalid: socket didn't refer to WebSocket, but instead to `net.Socket` connection on node's `httpServer`. Next question: how do you mount your router to that server?

Comment: @jsalonen, Updated the question

Comment: Are you using a load balancer like ELB/ALB in front of the server?

Comment: @jsalonen, No. I am quite new to AWS and I just created an ec2 instance and started the nodejs app from command line.

Comment: By the way: why are you using `http.createServer`? With express you should initialize your server using `var app = express()`.

Comment: @jsalonen, I use `var app = express();` to create the app. Then I create the server with `var server = http.createServer(app);`. This was how it was done in the tutorial I followed :)

Comment: I think thats redundant. Only thing you need is `app.listen()`: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app

Comment: I take my words back: its probably ok and not related. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17696801/express-js-app-listen-vs-server-listen

Comment: What does itemModel fetch call?

Comment: @jsalonen it fetches documents from a mongodb database.

Comment: And it does return part of the response? Or how do you know 5MB of data is replied? Also is the MongoDB server also in Amazon AWS or somewhere else? What is the latency between your EC2 and Mongo?

Comment: @jsalonen No. It simply returns all the documents it fetched. I checked what it returns by adding a log entry and couldn't find anything wrong.

Comment: What kind of code you use in client-side to handle the response?

Comment: I use android-async-http library in Android (http://loopj.com/android-async-http/). I also tried using Chrome Postman addon.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with both clients?

Comment: Yes. Issue exists in both.

Comment: The mongodb documents I return have some base64 encoded image data. That's why the reply is quite large. Don't know whether it has any relevance or not.

Comment: Have you timed how long the response takes to generate before failing?

Comment: It takes a very little time to fetch the documents from mongodb (about 1 second). After about 20 seconds, client reports that the server terminated the connection (it roughly receives about 1MB of the reply).

Comment: If I delete the documents from mongodb and keep only few documents, request succeeds.

Comment: What are the specs of your EC2 instance? Do you have other processes running? I'm assuming you are testing just against a single client. Also: what is the connection speed between your client / server?

Comment: It is a t2.micro instance (1 vCPU, 1GB memory). I am the only client.

Comment: How about connection speed between client/server?

Comment: I don't know whether there is any limitation from server side, but my internet connection is somewhat slow. (It only downloads 1 MB of the reply within 10 seocnds)

Comment: Well thats the issue then I guess. 1 MB in 10 seconds --> you get timeout of 30 secs before that 5 MB is transferred.

Comment: The timeout is not actually 30 seconds. It is 300 seconds. Also, I checked again and the connection always terminates at 8 seconds.

Comment: @jsalonen, I got to go now. Thanks for your effort to help. If you can think of anything else which could be the issue, please add it here.

Comment: @jsalonen, Setting the timeout for the http server did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting timeout for the HTTP server resolved the issue.

```
var server = http.createServer(app);
var port = app.get('port');
server.listen(port);
server.setTimeout(300000, function (socket) {
});
```