# Error: Request failed with status code 404 (Node.js + Vue.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I am little bit confused and need some help.

I write an HTTP server using **Node.js**,  and make an HTTP request from **Vue.js** to the HTTP server. Somehow it always return error like this:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at FtD3.t.exports (createError.js:16)
    at t.exports (settle.js:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.f.(:3010/anonymous function) (http://localhost:3010/static/js/vendor.1dc24385e2ad03071ff8.js:1312:88758)
```

It seems like url address don't correct cause error is 404 in browser. I check url address several times but did't notice something wrong. What I miss?

**P.S.** The main task to load file from remote sftp server from website. I use to that task [ssh2-sftp-client](https://github.com/jyu213/ssh2-sftp-client) library as backend side.

When user click the button, application run `getFile` function where we send post request to HTTP server.

Code inside **Vue.js** component:

```
getFile (fileName) {
    axios.post('http://localhost:3010/csv', {file_name: fileName}, {headers: {'Authorization': this.token}}).then(response => {
        console.log(response)
        this.showAlert('You download file successfully.', 'is-success', 'is-top')
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
        this.showAlert(error, 'is-danger', 'is-bottom')
    })
}
```

**app.js:**

```
const express = require('express');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const logger = require('morgan');
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const csvRouter = require('./server/routes/csv')

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use('/csv', csvRouter);

module.exports = app;
```

**routers/csv.js:**

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

const csvControllers = require('../controllers/csv')

router.get('/', csvControllers.getFile)

module.exports = router
```

**controllers/csv.js:**

```
const request = require('request')
const queryString = require('query-string')
let Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client')
let sftp = new Client()

const config = require('../config')

exports.getFile = (req, res) => {
  console.log(req)  // In console I don't notice nothing.
  let data = {
    file_name: req.query.file_name
  }
  let options = {
    method: 'port',
    json: true,
    header: {'Authorization': req.header.token},
    url: `http://localhost:3010/csv?` + queryString.stringify(data)
  }
  request(options, (error, response) => {
    console.log('Message')  // In console I don't notice nothing.
    if (response) {
      sftp.connect(config.sftpServer).then(() => {
        return sftp.get('/reports/' + data.file_name)
      }).then((chunk) => {
        console.log(chunk)
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
      })
    } else {
      response.status(500).send(error)
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems that `app.listen(port)` is missing in your `app.js` file:

```
app.listen(3000)
```

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html

Comment: No, I don't miss it. It just in other file. Inside `bin/www`. I use such code inside that file: `let port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3010')`, `app.set('port', port)`, then `const server = http.createServer(app)`. Finally `server.listen(port)` Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Bro, what would be better? Use `server.lister(port)` or `app.lister(port)`?

Comment: [app.listen vs server.listen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17696801/express-js-app-listen-vs-server-listen)

Comment: I have no other clue - everything else seems to be fine.

Answer (score -1):

In `controllers/csv.js` you never send a response. You should have a `res.send` or `res.render` or `res.json` somewhere.