# Adding GraphQL subscriptions to the existing express app using single server

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

GraphQL playground subscription fails with 400 error code.

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/graphql' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

I have an existing code based on express. I've integrated Apollo v2 this way:

```
const { ApolloServer, PubSub, gql } = require('apollo-server-express');

    ...

const app = express();

const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
     resolvers       
});


server.applyMiddleware({ app });

    ...

app.listen(port, () =>
    console.log(chalk.blue(`App listening on port ${port}!`)),
);
```

and then i start my existing app on port `3000` and can access the GraphQL playground on `http://localhost:3000/graphql`. All queries and mutations work as expected

Now I want to add subscriptions. Turns out I need to use an http server:

```
const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
server.installSubscriptionHandlers(httpServer);
```

and then listen to it on another port:

```
httpServer.listen(3005, () => {
    console.log(`Server ready at http://localhost:3005${server.graphqlPath}`);
     console.log(`Subscriptions ready at ws://localhost:3005${server.subscriptionsPath}`);
    });
```

So I have two servers running. My own on port `3000` and the subscriptions server on `3005`. Is that the right way? Is it the only way?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to call both `app.listen` and `httpServer.listen` -- calling `httpServer.listen` will expose both your Express app and the subscription server.

Additional reading: [Express.js - app.listen vs server.listen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17696801/express-js-app-listen-vs-server-listen)

Comment: `installSubscriptionHandlers` has to be passed an instance of [http.Server](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_server) which `app` is *not*. Calling `app.listen`, however, will return an instance of `http.Server` that can then be passed to `installSubscriptionHandlers` if you prefer to do that.

Comment: If your "existing code structure" requires you to use `app.listen`, though, you may just need to restructure your code.

Comment: Just looked into the internals of `installSubscriptionHandlers ` and seems like you are right - I need to change the approach.