# Socket.io client not connecting with server React and Express

Tags: reactjs, express, websocket, socket.io

I'm using react frontend with express backend.

React socket code

```
import io from "socket.io-client";

function ReactComponent() {
    const socket = io("http://localhost:5000");

    socket.on('connection', () => {
        console.log("connection")
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        socket.emit('new-user', "hello");
    }, []);

    return(<p>Test text</p>);
}
    
export default ReactComponent;
```

Express socket code

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log("New client connected");

    socket.on('new-user', (room) => {
        socket.join(room);
        socket.to(room).broadcast.emit('user-connected', "thx for info");
    })
});
```

From looking at the documentation and other examples, this should work and if it does, express should print out "New client connected" yet that doesn't happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took a while to find this. Hope this helps someone else in the future!

On the express I used to have:

```
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port);
```

Instead, it should have been:

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
var server = app.listen(port);

var io = require('socket.io')().listen(server);
```

Notice how there is no mention of the http module as most of the other answers require it.

A helpful thread to help understand the problem is here: [Express.js - app.listen vs server.listen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17696801/express-js-app-listen-vs-server-listen)

Additionally, the docs for this are here:
https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-initialization/

Answer (score 0):

You are not emitting to the listener called `connection` at your backend. You have to communicate to the listener at the backend

```
import io from "socket.io-client";

function ReactComponent() {
    const socket = io("http://localhost:5000");

    socket.emit('connection');
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have used `app.listen()` in your code, then you need to change it to `http.listen()`, and then it should work.

Because the `app` has been already passed while creating the `http` server. It means that this `http` needs to listen on some port and not the `app`.