# Why there is always request timeout error in heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, websocket, server, web-deployment

I just want to deploy a simple node js application on heroku but it always throws me a request timeout error, I don't know why? Actually, first I tried with my main project but it didn't work then I try with some basic node js code, and after deploying I literally got shocked because it is also not working. Is this some problem related to the WebSockets library or I am doing wrong (Please let me know), I am tired of searching for a solution to this problem.

**server.js**

```
const Socket = require("websocket").server
const http = require("http")

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {})

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
    console.log("Listening on port 3000...")
})

const webSocket = new Socket({ httpServer: server })

webSocket.on('request', (req) => {
    const connection = req.accept()
    console.log("open")

    connection.on('message', (message) => {
        const data = JSON.parse(message.utf8Data)

        if(data.type == "message"){
            console.log(data.mess);
            connection.send(JSON.stringify(data))
        }
    })
})
```

Please help me to get out of this.

Comment: Have you tried moving `server.listen` to the bottom of the file? It is really important

Comment: No, but how it is different to declare on top of the file?

Comment: Check out [this answer to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17697134/14575901)

Comment: Did you check that you ip is whitelisted  and port is open in heroku server?

Comment: I don't think that that's the cause of the problem 

Comment: @michael.grigoryan I tried declaring at the bottom of the file but it doesn't work either.